# Meaning of 有步骤地

Tags: meaning

I stumbled upon this text extolling the work of the Communist Party. It states:

> 此后，党在各个方面深入总结历史经验，制定了一系列正确的方针政策，有步骤地解决了许多历史遗留问题和实际生活中出现的新问题，推动着以经济建设为中心的各项事业沿着正确轨道健康发

My gut feeling is that 有步骤地 means „methodically“ or „step by step“, since the most literal meanings of the word seem to go back to walking slowly. But the PLC dictionary entry for 步骤 also lists “measure”.

So is “step by step, methodically” correct or is it ”with measures, actively“?

Comment: You are more correct than the dictionary. But I doubt there should be explanations other than "measure". For instance, it can be used to indicate a series of steps in a procedure such as "步骤一....步骤二....", or "按步骤進行" - advancing one's work following the procedure. There is an implied meaning "methodic", so in your case, it can mean "methodically resolved...".

Answer (score 1):

**有步骤** can be found in a few Pleco dictionaries:

One English:

*KEY*

> methodical, systematic

One French:

*KEF*

> systématique

And one German:

*HDD*

> operativ (A)

*有步骤地* can also be found in two Pleco example sentences:

This one from *PLC*:

> 有计划有步骤地进行工作
> yǒu jìhuà yǒu bùzhòu de jìnxíng gōngzuò
> work in a planned and methodical way

And this one from *Oxford*

> 有计划、有步骤地开展工作
> carry out the work step by step in a well-planned way

“Step by step, methodically” seems to be the winner here.